# Laravel - PHP/MySQL date range filter against date range in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am working on an application using Laravel and I am trying to filter records from the database. Here is the criteria:

In the database I have 2 date columns `[excluded_period_start]` and `[excluded_period_end]`. Both columns have date datatype.

Now I have 2 fields in my form `[start_date]` and `[end_date]`.

I want to get all the records excluding the period stored in the database. The code I am using is:

```
      $hotels = Hotel::whereHas('location' , function($query) use($searchOptions){


            if(trim($searchOptions['location']) != ''){
              $query->where('location_title', $searchOptions['location']);
            }

          })
          ->where('excluded_period_start', '<', $start)
          ->where('excluded_period_end', '>', $end)
          ->where('active', 1)
          ->take(10)
          ->paginate(10);
```

However, this only gives me results which comes between the range stored in my database but I want the results **outside** of that range.

I have tried many things like `->whereBetween()` but none of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial excluded_period can't be between your start and end:

```
          ->whereNotBetween('excluded_period_start', [$start, $end])
          ->whereNotBetween('excluded_period_end', [$start, $end])
```

Comment: let me give it a try.